# Error Using pointers to get memory address locations

Tags: c

I have since figured this out. Thank you...I'm new to C and having trouble getting the memory address of the variable that's assigned to the pointer.

What am I missing or not understanding here. The valueVariable needs to be declared. The pointerVariable needs to be declared and set to the &valueVariable. still unsure what %x does to be honest. TIA

```
int main () {

    double innerD, outerD, density, thickness;
    double *innerDPointer, *outerDPointer, *thicknessPointer, *densityPointer;

    innerD = 0.0;
    outerD = 0.0;
    density = 0.0;
    thickness = 0.0;

    innerDPointer = &innerD;
    outerDPointer = &outerD;
    densityPointer = &density;
    thicknessPointer = &thickness;

    int quantity;
    int *quantityPointer;

    quantityPointer = &quantity;

    printf("\nAddress of innerD variable: %x\n", &innerD);
    printf("\nAddress of outerD variable: %x\n", &outerD);
    printf("\nAddress of density variable: %x\n", &density);
    printf("\nAddress of thickness variable: %x\n", &thickness);
    printf("\nAddress of quantity variable: %x\n", &quantity);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need few minutes to read https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Comment: you need %p not %x - https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html. I mean the error message is very clear

Comment: @SparKot you are an MVP thanks. I was looking for one of these.

Comment: Use printf format specifier `%p` to print a pointer. It expects a corresponding argument of type `void *`, so arguments of other pointer types should be explicitly converted with a `(void *)` cast.

Comment: @pm100 I couldn't find a proper guide for the % items. My professor hasn't gone over this yet. Just figuring it out on my own. Thanks for your help

Comment: This is C, not C++, function arguments of type void * accept any pointer type; no cast needed or desired.

Comment: @jTruBela - just google 'man <xxxx>` like `man printf` ('man' is short for manual).

Comment: What is your question? What output do you get and what do you expect? What is the "error" you mention in the question title?

Comment: Does anyone know how to get the memory address for a defined constant? ie. #define PI 3.14159

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to access a variable's address, you use the `&` operator in front of the variable. Thus, when you use printf with `&innerD` as a second parameter, you are telling printf to print your line and to replace %x with a hexadecimal value, which is `&innerD`. Typically, to print an adress, you would use the %p format. The %x is meant to print an unsigned int in hexadecimal form, and that's why you have a warning, because you're passing an `double *`, and not an `unsigned int`

That being said, note that not at any moment you have to use a new `int *` variable since you directly passed the variable address to printf.

```
int main()
{
    double innerD, outerD, density, thickness;

    innerD = 0.0;
    outerD = 0.0;
    density = 0.0;
    thickness = 0.0;

    int quantity;

    printf("\nAddress of innerD variable: %p\n", &innerD);
    printf("\nAddress of outerD variable: %p\n", &outerD);
    printf("\nAddress of density variable: %p\n", &density);
    printf("\nAddress of thickness variable: %p\n", &thickness);
    printf("\nAddress of quantity variable: %p\n", &quantity);

    return 0;
}
```

to find more details on how to use printf flags, enter the command `man 3 printf` in your terminal, if you use a unix system (mac  or linux)